# MongoDB: Getting document and only one object of an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I got multiple documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "sgG6G9XTvvjj7uxwQ",
    "title" : "A title",
    "notes" : [
        {
            "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM",
            "timestamp" : 1453731403807,
            "message" : "some text",
            "name" : "Tom"
        },
        {
            "id" : "BAHx9KeKjuMePce6f",
            "timestamp" : 1453731403808,
            "message" : "some text",
            "name" : "Bob"
        },
        {
            "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM",
            "timestamp" : 1453731403809,
            "message" : "some text",
            "name" : "Tom"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get this document by using this `find`-query:

```
Collection.find({}, { sort: { title: 1 }});
```

But I don't need the complete `notes` field. I'm only interested in the `id` of the last note-object. That means I have to order all notes object by timestamp and just take the first (=newest) one.

I'm not quite sure, if I can do that by the `find`-query or if I have to do that after getting the complete data.

So the best result for me would be:

```
{
    "_id" : "sgG6G9XTvvjj7uxwQ",
    "title" : "A title",
    "notes" : [
        {
            "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) projection to limit the number of array elements returned. For example:

```
db.collection.find({}, {title: 1, "notes.id": 1, notes: {$slice: 1}}).sort({title: 1});
```

Will return:

```
{
        "_id" : "sgG6G9XTvvjj7uxwQ",
        "title" : "A title",
        "notes" : [
                {
                        "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: That's quite nice. Think I have to keep the timestamp and order also for timestamp. How would I do a map reduce on client?

Comment: There's a good explanation of [Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) on the MongoDB Docs website [docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)

Comment: I have found a better way to do it with the [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) projection. I have updated my answer. I think this correctly solves your issue. Thanks for accepting my answer ;-)

Comment: If you need other items included in the output, just add them to the projection, e.g. `"notes.message": 1`, you can also just exclude the items you *don't* want, e.g. `Collection.find({},{"notes.message": -1})` will return everything except the message in each element of the notes array. You can read more about this in the [db.collection.find()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) reference in the MongoDB Docs: [docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)